# cant access new frameworks with xcode 3.2?

Tags: iphone

i had x code 3.1 and sdk 3.2 but i wanted to use new frameworks so i installed x code 3.2 but i cannot run new applications now.can anyone tell what is the problem?i also want to tell that i installed only x code not iphone sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS/iPhone development you need to download the complete Xcode 3.2.4 + SDK 4.1 .dmg (over 2GB image) from the [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).  Other combinations than the current and prior downloads aren't tested and rarely work.

Comment: i have x code 3.2.2+sdk 3.2.4 can i use core telephony and message composer in this composition?